# Simultaneous reception and sending of datagrams

Tags: java, datagram

There are a code that receaving peer-to-peer messages.

```
 try {
            DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(1050);
            DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024], 1024);
            while (true) {
                AscMessage();
                ds.receive(pack);
                System.out.println(new String(pack.getData()));
            }
        }
            catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
}
```

There is a code that sends a peer-to-peer message.

```
public void AscMessage(){
        System.out.print(">");
        final Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String s1 = in.nextLine ();
        this.sendMessage(s1);
    }

   public void sendMessage(String mes){

    try{

        byte[] data = mes.getBytes();

        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);

        DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, addr, port);

        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();

        ds.send(pack);

        ds.close();

    }catch(IOException e){

        System.err.println(e);

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Sender sndr = new Sender("localhost", 1050);

    while (true){
        sndr.AscMessage();
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < args.length; k++)
        sndr.sendMessage(args[k]);

}
```

How can they be combined? Wait for a new message, but at the same time send.
Is it necessary to use two ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, one port is ok. You either use two threads or you use the features of Java 8 for asynchronous waiting with select.